# Can't add foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I m trying to add a foreign key to table `table2` from `table1`. But i got an error like this... what is the problem...help

```
Error

SQL query:

ALTER TABLE `table2` ADD FOREIGN KEY ( `bus_id` ) REFERENCES `db1`.`table1` (
`bus_id`
) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db1`.`#sql-664_e2`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-664_e2_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`bus_id`) REFERENCES `table1` (`bus_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

**Structure of table1**

[image]

**Structure of table2**

[image]

Comment: I can't see the structures because I'm at work but it seems like there is an entry in table1 that has a bus_id that's not in table2 and since your foreign key states that when you delete a table2 entry, it should be removed from table1 ... it's giving you an error...

Comment: @QuadroQ You're wrong.table1 is referenced table, so it can have values not found in table2.But table2 can not have bus_id values which are not in table1.

Comment: yeah ... maybe i got it all upside down... :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tables have some data. Check that all values stored in `table2`.`bus_id` are correct; all these values have to be in `table1`.`bus_id`.

Run this query to view wrong `bus_id` values in `table2`:

```
SELECT t2.bus_id AS inconsistent_bus_id FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1
  ON t1.bus_id = t2.bus_id
WHERE t1.bus_id IS NULL
```

Remove this records from `table2`, or add this `bus_id` to the `table1`. Then try to create foreign key again.

Answer (score 1):

To get more info run following command:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```

I expect that there is data mismatch, eg. table2 contain values in column bus_id which is not found in table1.

try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT bus_id FROM table2 WHERE 
    bus_id NOT IN (SELECT bus_id FROM table1)
```

Also make sure that both tables uses InnoDB as storage engine.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any error on your `ALTER` statement. The main reason is that maybe there are already records existed on `table2` which `bus_id` are not on `table1`. So the best solution you can do is to empty first table2 and run the alter statement again.